# How to disable a button based on the role of logged in user in ASP .net

Tags: asp.net

I have following role in my  application,
User, Visitor and Admin.
In my application i want to give access for delete button to User and Admin and not to User in ASP .net.
How would i implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IsInRole`

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("User"))
{
    Button1.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: If i have more than one button(button2,button3..and so on) in the same page , can i do as below,
if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("User"))
{
    Button1.Enabled = true;
    Button2.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;  
    Button2.Enabled = false;

}

Comment: I have <input onclick="window.history.back()" type="button" class= "btnGrid" name="B_Back" id="B_Back" accesskey="B" value="Back"  /></td>  code in my .aspx page and when i am tring the code 
if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("User") || User.IsInRole("Coord"))
        {
            B_Back.Enabled = true;
            
        }
        else
        {
            B_Back.Enabled = false;
           
        }
it is giving me following error,
The name 'B_Back' does not exist in the current context

Comment: add runat=server to the butotn

Comment: After adding runat=server, i am getting following error
'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled' and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There is a difference between `<button runat=server>` and `<asp:Button runat=server>`